# How does one install a package like amstex on MiKTeX

Tags: packages, installing, mac

I want to use `amstex` in my MiKTeX on my Mac.  I cannot find any instructions on how to install any package.  Are there instructions?  If not, how is it done.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why didn't you install MacTeX on your Mac? Had you installed the full MacTeX distribution, you wouldn't have to ask about installing individual packages.

Comment: @Mico MiKTeX can run on High Sierra

Comment: @egreg - MacTeX does too. (At least, MacTeX2018 runs just fine on my MacOS 10.13.5 High Sierra laptop, which is a bit more than 4 years old by now.)

Comment: @Mico Yes, of course, but apparently the OP has MiKTeX.

Comment: @egreg - I'm aware there's a version of MikTeX for MacOS. My initial comment was prompted by the OP's apparent unawareness of how to install packages with (a likely initially minimal version of) MiKTeX for MacOS. I was trying to suggest to the OP that he/she install a (complete) version of MacTeX and thus not have to worry about obtaining packages that weren't downloaded and installed by default. I suppose another easy suggestion would have been that the OP re-install a complete version of MiKTeX, with all packages downloaded immediately...

Comment: why amstex? not even the AMS use amstex these days.

Comment: HI,  I thought I downloaded all of MiKTeX onto my mac.  I want to use amsmath and amsfonts because I need to line up systems of equation with at least three imaginary vertical lines.  I read that \eqalign can do that.  I am happy to use another method.  \eqalign does not work well in MiKTeX.  Is there a better way?  How do I know if I have all of MiKTeX?  Is it worth switching to MacTeX?   Thanks so much, Jaime

Comment: @Jaime'Jimmy'CuevasDermody -- Please add the information to your question that you want to use `amstex` and `amsfonts`.  `amstex` is an outdated "flavor" of TeX, parallel to LaTeX.  So your question does not really ask for what you want or need.

Answer (score 2):

I am using MiKTeX on Windows, I do not know MiKTeX on MAC.

With the current MiKTeX Console you can find out which packages are installed on your system and if there are packages available, but not installed on your system.

Start the MiKTeX Console and click on "Packages" (left red circle in screenshot). Then you get a list of packages. Now click on "Installed on" (right red circle) to sort packages list. After that you can see not installed packages (No entry in column "Installed on", see red marking a) and installed packages (see red marking b).

[image]

To find in the list of available and installed packages special packag(s) like your searched `amstex` you can type the name in the writing field, in the next screenshot marked with a red circle. Then click on the symbol right (see red arrow). After that you get a reduced list of packages showed, containing the searched letters. In the shown screenshot below you can see that that package is already installed on my system.

[image]

If you need to install it click on the name in the list (the line gets blue) and click on the + sign (red circle; in my case not activated, because the current package is already installed) to get marked package installed.

[image]

I do not think that MiKTeX Console will react very different on MAC. I can you only show the windows version ...

Comment: In a comment, the OP refers to *LaTeX* packages, in particular `amsmath`.  `amstex`, in this context, is obsolete, and that package is present only for application to old, preexisting documents.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Well, which context do you mean (sorry, my english is school english only)? Because there is an mwe missing I can only answer in a general form. Can you add an better answer? Or extend my answer?